# Troubleshooting Silicon Labs CP120x USB to UART Bridge (COM4) Driver Start Issue (Code 10)

Tags: driver, iot, esp32

I am creating an IOT project, where I use ESP32 Cam. To upload the required code to ESP32 Cam using Arduino IDE, it requires USB to UART port driver. This driver is not present by default, so I downloaded it from [silabs](https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers?tab=downloads)

(Silicon Labs) official website. The problem is the driver got installed but its status is showing the message
***This device cannot start. (Code 10)***

***The specified request is not a valid operation for the target device.***

I have tried to install and reinstall, updated the driver and seen lots of videos on the internet, still that error is not resolved. Can anyone help me with this? I have Windows 11 64bit operating system.

I want someone to please give me a solution so that the error message should be displayed as:

***The device is working properly***